# What class structure will mimic an XML document with alternating tags

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am attempting to reproduce a XML file structure programmatically using c#. The file structure is giving me difficulties in that it makes use of a tag as an empty data set or a parent tag for child elements under nodes. As an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
      <E></E>
      <E></E>
      <F>false</F>
      <F>true</F>
      <F>false</F>
      <G>
        <H/>
      </G>
    </C>
    <B>
      <D>
        <E>continue</E>
        <G>
          <F>false</F>
          <E>1</E>
        </G>
      </D>
      <B/>
      <D>
        <E></E>
      </D>
      <B/>
    </B>
  </B>
</A>
```

The specific nodes giving me difficulty are the `<B>` nodes. I'm not sure how to structure the class so that it can contain a list of node elements in addition to itself which may or may not have values and have that be serialized into an XML document. Any help would be welcome, it may be complicated to explain so I am happy to elaborate.

Comment: You may use https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ to get the class-structure

Comment: Can you simplify that a bit to indicate the specific node(s) where you are having a problem?  Do you need to generate the alternating nodes when *serializing*, or only handle them when *deserializing*? @HimBromBeere - https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ may not create a good result in complex [`<xsd:choice>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256109(v%3Dvs.100)) + [`<xsd:sequence>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256089(v%3Dvs.100)) scenarios, which we seem to have here.

Comment: See a posting I answer earlier today : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181213/linq-to-xml-how-to-query-listt-with-linq-recursively/58181828#58181828

Comment: @dbc I won't need to worry about deserializing, only serializing my classes to XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we were to make a schema for your `<B>` node, it would consist of a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256089(v%3Dvs.100)) of [choice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256109(v%3Dvs.100)) nodes, where an element of type `<C>`, `<D>`, or `<B>` itself might be chosen.

If we were to model this in c#, the natural way to do so would be to use a list of polymorphic objects, the items of which would correspond to the three element types. Luckily, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643424/3744182) to *[Using XmlSerializer to serialize derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1643139/3744182)* by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell), this scenario is supported by `XmlSerializer` by annotating the polymorphic collection with [`[XmlElement(String, Type)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlElementAttribute__ctor_System_Type_) attributes, one for each concrete type that might appear in the collection.

Thus, you can define your data model as follows:

```
public class BaseNode 
{
}

public class B : BaseNode
{
    [XmlElement("B", typeof(B))]
    [XmlElement("C", typeof(C))]
    [XmlElement("D", typeof(D))]
    public List<BaseNode> Nodes { get; } = new List<BaseNode>();
}

public class C : BaseNode
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="E")]
    public List<string> E { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="F")]
    public List<bool> F { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="G")]
    public G1 G { get; set; }
}

public class D : BaseNode
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="E")]
    public string E { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName="G")]
    public G2 G { get; set; }
}

public class G1
{
    public string H { get; set; }
}

public class G2 
{
    public string F { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("A")]
public class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- I made the 3 types that can appear in the `B.Nodes` collection inherit from a common ancestor `BaseNode`, so that it is not possible to add irrelevant items into the collection at runtime.  If you don't want this, you could eliminate `BaseNode` and declare your collection as a `List<object>`.
- It is my experience that the various tools mentioned in *[Generate C# class from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4203540/3744182)* do not always generate optimal c# classes from XML that has complex [`<xsd:choice>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256109(v%3Dvs.100)) + [`<xsd:sequence>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256089(v%3Dvs.100)) scenarios.

  If you had a proper XSD, however, the tools from *[How to generate .NET 4.0 classes from xsd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5217665/3744182)* would generate correct c# classes.
- In your example you have two nodes named `<G>` that appear to have different schemas, so I had to create two types `G1` and `G2`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QQrKTe).

Comment: Thank you! Yes That appears to provide the structure I am looking for, I have a lot more elements to add (not shown in my original question) but I believe I am on the right track.